# SQL Query to Find Repeat Customers

Tags: sql, sql-server, relational-division

In an [orders] table, some rows have the same value for the email column meaning they are repeat customers.

```
prodid   | email
---------|---------------------
123      | test@test.com
456      | hi@there.com
789      | test@test.com
...
```

What I am trying to do is pass in to the query 2 prodid's (ex: 123 and 789) and the results should be the email addresses that exist for both of those prodid's.

What SQL statement should I use to find these rows?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: This shouldn't have been marked as a duplicate question

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT Email FROM yourTable 
GROUP BY email
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Try a group by and having

Comment: Yup +1. I agree with TGH.  And depending on what language you are programming in, you can create the text list of numbers  "123,456" from an array [123,456] by using a standard function to 'glue' them together with a comma.  PHP: implode, python: join, ...

Comment: This does not specify the two required products.  I would pass in two numbers and the email addresses returned should be those that have orders for both of those products (they may have other products, i only care about the ones passed in though).

Answer (score 2):

you can use intersect to get the emails that are common between both.

```
select email from tableA where prodid in ( 123)
intersect
select email from tableA where prodid in (456)
```

Comment: I think that this is it.  I did not know about intersect, I guess it is like a "distinct" and "union" for multiple queries?

Comment: @Dennis `INTERSECT` combines two queries and returns all result rows that are common for both queries.